# Doctrine 2 orm:schema-tool:create

Tags: doctrine

I have `model` as follow

```
/**
 * @Id
 * @Column(type="integer",nullable=false)
 * @generatedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;
/**
 * @Column(type="string",nullable=false,unique=true)
 */
private $email;
/**
 * @Column(type="string",length=64,nullable=false)
 */
private $password;
/**
 * @Column(type="string",nullable=false)
 */
private $first_name;
/**
 * @Coulmn(type="string",nullable=false)
 */
private $last_name;
```

When I run

```
orm:schema-tool:create
```

it generate the table on the database with all fields except `Last_name` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you have a typo: `@Coulmn(type="string",nullable=false)` should be `@Column(type="string",nullable=false)`

Comment: ah sorry :)) miss type <3 thnx